# input type range with smaller :active slider doesn't always work on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a standard html5 range input (aka slider) where I make the slider thumb (handle) smaller when the slider is active. This works fine in all web browsers I need to support, except for Safari on iOS (only tried on iPhone).

As soon as I change the width and height css attributes in the :active class it gets really hard to grab the slider handle to change the value. It works sometimes, but not always. The slider gets active, so the size changes, but the slider is "stuck". It doesn't follow my finger when I try to slide it.

Here's a CodePen with two sliders, the top one works flawlessly, the bottom one is sometimes difficult to "grab" on Safari https://codepen.io/tobbe_lundberg/pen/wvervQx

And here's the code for it:

```css
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: pink;
  height: 4px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  background: pink;
  margin-top: -24px;
}

input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  margin-top: -24px;
}

input.resize[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1"/>
<input class="resize" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1"/>
```

How can I make the resize effect work on Safari as well, using only CSS?

Comment: This isn't possible with only CSS. You will need to add a `mousedown` or `touchstart` in JavaScript or jQuery for this.

Comment: @Hacker Why do you say this? It works fine if I don't resize the handle in :active. What is it about the resize that requires JS?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The way I worked around it, which might not work for you (and is somewhat of a hack,) is to to make the thumb visually smaller but not actually smaller. You can use a near-transparent border (or one with the same color as the background) that counteracts the reduced size of the visible part.

---

Too long to fit in a comment but did you solve this? I'm having problems that seem exactly the same as yours with the difference that I have a very thin slider thumb to start with.

Seeing your problem I tried to leverage the reverse as a solution: make the slider thumb much larger when active. This actually works like a charm when it comes to making it easier to grab the thumb.

One thing I noticed though, and I figure this could be one of the reasons behind the problems you're seeing: changing the slider thumb actually changes the range of the slider and thus the thumb position with it. If you make the thumb very large, you'll notice that the full range becomes spread over a very short distance.

Comment: I tried your solution (manipulating border size). And it does resolve the issue. But I only tried it with a color that's the same as the background. But this "hides" the track around the thumb. Using a near-transparent border does seem like it would have worked. What I ended up doing was just disabling the change of size on mobile. The user's finger will mostly be covering the slider thumb anyways...